# raspberry 400 hdmi output does not follow config.txt

Tags: hdmi, config.txt, 1080p

Have my new raspberry 400 with current Raspberry OS and connected a TV by the official micro-HDMI-cable. There is no problem getting an image, but it always goes to 1080p@50 mode (TV tells me that, and the display is flickering). Tried different solutions, but none helped. In /boot/config.txt I have (tested with different combinations):

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
hdmi_force_mode=1
```

Tried also different groups and modes, like `hdmi_group=1` and `hdmi_mode=16`.

`kmsprint` tells me `1920x1080i@50` on graphical display and `1920x1080i@60` on tty1.

What works (I use this as a workaround):

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080
```

What is wrong in /boot/config.txt?

Comment: "current Raspberry OS" is meaningless - which OS? Bullseye doesn't use anything display related in`/boot/config.txt` and ignores practically anything you set.

Comment: Yes, it's Bullseye (2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64.img). `hdmi_safe=1` in config.txt is respected; but where else then is the HDMI configuration done?

Comment: Use the Screen Configuration menu

Comment: The Screen Configuration Menu is not available, as I do not use LXDE (prefer xfce4). And this only sets the resolution for the garphical screen when logging in (not tty)

Answer (score 0):

Following the ideas from [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82686/custom-screen-resolution-for-android-on-raspberry-pi-3/98906#98906)  I found two (not really satisfying) solutions:

a) Add a desktop file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` with contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=xrandr1080p
Comment=
Exec=xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080
Icon=preferences-desktop-display
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

After logging in to the graphical desktop, this will modify the mode to 1080p@60. But on `tty` it still is 1080i@60.

b) Use `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` instead of `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d` in `/boot/config.txt`. This works and respects the hdmi settings in `config.txt`. I do not know whether there are any drawbacks with this solution; but I do not use the raspberry for video works, and only need a working desktop and GUI.